# jQuery tablesorter - Colspan sort second column

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have the following table with jquery tablesorter enhanced:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Name</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="london" value="1" /></td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>124</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="oslo" value="1" /></td>
            <td>Oslo</td>
            <td>66</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="athens" value="1" /></td>
            <td>Athens</td>
            <td>87</td>
        </tr>
    </tbod>
</table>
```

My problem now, is that if I click on the "Name" column header, the table isn't sorted, since tablesorter tries to sort the first column which is an checkbox in each row.

Is there a way to tell tablesorter, to sort the second column instead of the frist one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried some solutions, but the only one worked for me is to add a hidden span in the first td-column With the value of the second column in it:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Name</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span style="display: none;">London</span><input type="checkbox" name="london" value="1" /></td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>124</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span style="display: none;">Oslo</span><input type="checkbox" name="oslo" value="1" /></td>
            <td>Oslo</td>
            <td>66</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span style="display: none;">Athens</span><input type="checkbox" name="athens" value="1" /></td>
            <td>Athens</td>
            <td>87</td>
        </tr>
    </tbod>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have answere to your question but I can tell u alternative approach. Instead of using colspan="2", use the following code

```
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th style="display:none"></tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Hello, I tried this solution before, but the problem with this is, that then, there are more th's then td's in a row and because of that, the table is destroyed.

Comment: How th column will be more than td. U r having 3 td tag in each row. So add 3 th tag and hide first <th> tag.
<tr>
<th style="display:none"></th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Value</th>
</tr>
This is having 3 th tag(I'm not using colspan)
<tbody><tr>
<td>Checkbox</td>
<td>London</td>
<td>122</td></tr>
</tbody>
Its having 3 td column.

Comment: @Krishna  bernhard means it visually, not logically. I also ran into identical issue. When first <th> isn't displayed, the following two <th>s are pushed to the left and this is "destroy"ing the table visually.